# Determine where physicsbody is touching

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I've been trying to research this and work with different methods but am not having much luck.  I am developing a platformer game, and I'd like to tell if my character is touching the wall (hitting on the side) or when he is touching the ground (hitting on the bottom).

I've attempted to calculate this using the contactPoint location between the two bodies, but it's often impossible to tell if the character is hitting a side wall with his feet or hitting the ground with his feet.

I've read about using sensors, whose physicsBodies don't have a collisionBitMask but instead just use the contactTestBitMask.  I've created two SKNodes with physicsBodies, one for the sides and one for the feet, but if I make them volume-based, connected with a joint to my character, the mass of the sensors makes various buggy things happen like getting stuck in the ground or being too heavy.

If I make them edge-based, they don't move with my character, and I have to update them manually which usually lags behind.

I know this is not a new concept, but I cannot find how to implement this.  My question is, using SpriteKit, how do I determine if my player is touching the ground vs. touching his head vs. touching the sides of his bodies.

Thank you!

Comment: why not set the mass of the volume based sensors to zero?

Comment: Hey @rakeshbs - doing this appears to cause some physics oddities, where they fall through the floor, pull my character into the floor, etc.  If this is the most common way to handle this, I might need to revisit my code, but I didn't know if I was on the right track with it.